# Merge two arrays by different order conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Let's say that I have two arrays:

```
Apple.where(color: red).order(:date_picked)
```

and

```
Apple.where(color: green).order(:date_eaten)
```

How can I merge both arrays, while still maintaining their order conditions?

So that overall, the final merged list is sorted by date, while the dates used are by the previous arrays order criteria?

Can I make exceptions in the .order for different conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Query for both colors at the same time:

```
Apple.where(color: %w[red green])
```

and then use a CASE statement in the `order` call to choose which column to order by based on the `color`:

```
Apple.where(color: %w[red green])
     .order("case color when 'red' then date_picked when 'green' then date_eaten end")
```

You can `ORDER BY` any expression you want.

If you think this might end up in a larger query chain (which might involve JOINs) then you might want to qualify the column names:

```
Apple.where(color: %w[red green])
     .order("case apples.color when 'red' then apples.date_picked when 'green' then apples.date_eaten end")
```

but that verbosity isn't necessary in a one-off query.

Comment: Thanks! Okay, now, to follow-up, what would be the correct syntax to make the order :desc while writing it in the case statement? As well, is it possible to have chained conditionals? i.e. .order(:date_eaten, :apple_count) within the case statement?

Comment: `case ... end desc`, and `order(:a, :b)` is the same as `order('a', 'b')` so you can `order('case ... end', :apple_count)` if you want.

Comment: Thanks so much! You are great!